# Cannot find generator 'init' in ionic/capacitor with nx

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, monorepo

I'm trying to create nx workspace with ionic capacitor.

1. Able to create nx workspace -> SUCCESS
2. Able to install `npm install --save-dev @nxtend/ionic-angular` -> SUCCESS
3. nx generate @nxtend/ionic-angular:init -> FAILED

`Unable to resolve @nxtend/ionic-angular:init. Cannot find generator 'init' in node_modules/@nxtend/ionic-angular/generators.json.`

nx report says:

```
  Node : 16.10.0
  OS   : darwin x64
  npm  : 7.24.0
  
  nx : 13.0.0
  @nrwl/angular : 13.10.6
  @nrwl/cli : 13.0.0
  @nrwl/cypress : 13.10.6
  @nrwl/devkit : 13.0.0
  @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : Not Found
  @nrwl/express : Not Found
  @nrwl/jest : 13.0.0
  @nrwl/linter : 13.0.0
  @nrwl/nest : Not Found
  @nrwl/next : Not Found
  @nrwl/node : Not Found
  @nrwl/nx-cloud : 14.2.0
  @nrwl/react : Not Found
  @nrwl/schematics : Not Found
  @nrwl/tao : 13.0.0
  @nrwl/web : Not Found
  @nrwl/workspace : 13.0.0
  @nrwl/storybook : 13.10.6
  @nrwl/gatsby : Not Found
  typescript : 4.3.5
```

I'm follow this tutorial:
https://ionicframework.com/blog/ionic-angular-monorepos-with-nx/

`Edited:`

1. `npx create-nx-workspace@13.0.0 -> Success`
2. `npm install --save-dev @nxtend/ionic-angular -> Success`

But getting this

[image]

and for latest workspace version getting version dependency error like this:

1. `npx create-nx-workspace -> Success`
2. `npm install --save-dev @nxtend/ionic-angular -> Failed`

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue related to `nrwl/nx-labs`:

1. https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/10776
2. https://github.com/nrwl/nx-labs/issues/85

`app-root` was removed and is not required anymore.
Version v14.4.2 of `nrwl/nx-labs` should fix it.